# Proxy for SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, proxy

I have a desktop application for Windows, written in .net, which acts as a client to a remote SQL Server hosted at our company. Basically the application queries SQL Server (via Linq to Sql) and displays the results.

Now someone asked me to add *proxy support* to the application, because he does not always have an internet connection on his laptop. He wants to do like in Internet Explorer, where he goes to

```
Tools > Internet options > Connections > LAN settings > Use a proxy server
```

and there he types the address of his proxy server.

My questions are:

1. does this request even make sense for SQL Server? I mean, this is not HTTP, I think there is a different protocol for SQL Server. Will his proxy support this?
2. where do I start? What code must I change? How does the code look like?

Thanks

Comment: Proxy support is for ISP, provider, etc. Not for the application itself. It doesn't matter for web application is it used by direct connection or connection was proxied. Both of them will be HTTP requests. And what `because he does not always have an internet connection` means? Maybe question is about offline applications? What is connection between proxy and missing internet connection?

Comment: unfortunately the request was phrased like that. He basically wants a dialog box in my app where to enter the proxy address, like he does in internet explorer, and he expects the app to then be able to talk to Sql Server... But in my code I wouldn't know what to do with the address he enters...

Comment: oh, it's desktop application, not web. Then you can display such dialog and then change proxy settings. But by default .Net application uses system proxy settings that specified in usual Internet Options dialog. Based on the article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216415 - SQL Server at least supports Microsoft Proxy, not sure will other proxies be able to proxy SQL server connections...

Comment: If you are using port 1433 connections direct across the Internet, you are already in a state of original sin.

Comment: Yes I am using Linq to Sql to talk directly to Sql Server across the internet. I am not using an application server inbetween because I have stored procedures. So the app does not have permission to alter tables, but only to execute stored procedures, which require a user and password as parameters, so they can't do damage.

Comment: Did you find a solution for that @seguso ? I am having the same problem in here.

Comment: Sorry Tito, I didn't.